# Compute $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2r}}{(1+x^2)^m}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(m-1/2)}dx$ using the beta function

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

I am in the middle of a problem and I have been working on this integral for a while:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2r}}{(1+x^2)^m}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(1/2) \Gamma(m-1/2)}dx
$$
Which I identified the integrand on the right to be the beta function $B(\frac{1}{2},m-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\Gamma(1/2) \Gamma(m-1/2)}{\Gamma(m)}$.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{B(\frac{1}{2},m-\frac{1}{2})}&\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2r}}{(1+x^2)^m}dx \\
= \frac{1}{B(\frac{1}{2},m-\frac{1}{2})}&\int^\infty_0 x^r(1-x)^{-m}\cdot x^r(1+x)^{-m} dx
\end{align}

In the bottom integral the integrand $x^r(1-x)^{-m}$ is the integrand for [the beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Anyways, I cannot figure out how to proceed past this, but I am sure I just need to put it in some form of the beta function. Also in this problem, I am supposed to discover that the integral only exists when $2r < 2m -1$.

Comment: As far as I understand $(1-x)^{-m} (1+x)^{-m} \ne (1+x^2)^{-m}$

Comment: Use $x=\tan u,\,y=\sin^2u$, i.e. $y=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$, or equivalently $x^2=\frac{y}{1-y}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2r}}{(1+x^2)^{m}} dx = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{t^{r-1/2}}{(1+t)^m} dt = \int_1^{\infty}(z-1)^{r-1/2} \dfrac{1}{z^m} dz$$

Now use $z = \dfrac{1}{x}$